# Knative Function

Tags: jmeter, serverless, knative, knative-functions

Which components I have to install/build to run a Python function that receives HTTP request and replies with a confirmation message. The header of this request includes a value, which represents a temperature reading?

I will use JMeter to test Knative performance, parameter: response time, throughput, success rate.